# write multiple lines in csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have this simple python script:

```
ex = ['line 1\n', 'line 2\n', 'line 3\n']
str_ex = ' '.join(ex)
```

I want to write this to a csv file using f.write, but it writes each string on a new line.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `'\n'` is a newline character. Do you want to discard it? What is your exact expected output? Also, you probably want to use a comma as a separator: `','.join(ex)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
ex = ['line 1\\n', 'line 2\\n', 'line 3\\n']
str_ex = ' '.join(ex)
```